Can some one tell me why my apk is not compiling i have checked the codes many times but its not not comiling
I want to mod a game and I have completed it, but now it is not compiling even if I had tried by recompiling its original decompiled apk, but its not working.
Can someone help me out?
it says:
D:\MOD\APK_Toolkit_by_0xd00d\1 - Decompiled\mini militia hacked (R&Y)_4.2.8.apk\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml:1:error:not well -formed(invalid token)

and in second line it says:
unable to open D:\mod\APK-Toolkit_by-0xd00dz\2 - compiled\mini militia hacked (R&Y)_4.2.8.apk'as zip archive

I am new and I want someone to guide me what to do next.

You have provided too less information; the problem could be anything, firstly you need to provide structure of your project and the code that is causing the problem. For now call I can say is there is something wrong with 'icon.xml' file in line 1. it could probably be Tag related error

What commands do you use for decompiling and recompiling? Please edit your question and describe the commands you use for both and the used tool versions.

As the others mentioned: This is not enough information to help you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
